# Create multiple Azure VMs using the copy object

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I've got an ARM Template and Parameter file which successfully deploys a domain-joined VM in Azure.

- Virtual Machine
- NIC
- OS Disk

It needs updated to deploy 500 VMs incrementing name suffix -01, -02, -03 etc. I'm trying to use copy object in the resources section of my template but running into issues so I wish to review how I'm approaching this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-multiple-instances

Snippet from original ARM Template

```
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[variables('nicName')]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[parameters('subnetID')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix]",
                    "adminUsername": "[variables('vmSettings').adminUserName]",
                    "adminPassword": "[variables('vmSettings').adminPassword]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]",
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('dnsLabelPrefix'), '-os')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [ ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'))]"
            ]
        },
```

1. Do I simply use **copy** on VM or have to add this as well on NIC and OS Disk?
2. One of the syntax I've tried. Sample syntax I could retry would be useful.

```
"name": "[concat(variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix), copyIndex()]"
```

EDIT:
Updated the ARM Template added missing right parentheses ")" and hardcoding "count" value 3 for now to simplify testing. Latest version is

```
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex())]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "nicLoop",
                "count": 3
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[parameters('subnetID')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix, '-', copyIndex())]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "vmLoop",
                "count": 3
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix]",
                    "adminUsername": "[variables('vmSettings').adminUserName]",
                    "adminPassword": "[variables('vmSettings').adminPassword]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]",
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('dnsLabelPrefix'), '-os')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [ ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex()))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex()))]"
            ]
        },
```

Latest error:

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 9:41:51 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmname' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.`

Parameter file has this variable

```
        "dnsLabelPrefix": { "value": "vmname" },
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Why not give any response? Is it works for you?!

Comment: Sorry for delayed response as I ran into more issues. There were missing ")" See Edit in original post above.
I'm trying to figure out where else to insert copyIndex() to increment value of dnsLabelPrefix variable each loop.

Comment: The error means maybe you forgot to define the variable used in the virtual machine name. And I do not really understand what do you mean? As I see you just copy my answer to your question.

Comment: dnsLabelPrefix variable is used for naming nicName, vmNamePrefix, osDisk, VM Extensions. So I'm thinking its value needs incremented as well.
It's value is set in the Parameters file but I'm not sure if copyIndex() can be used in that file.

Comment: I don't think you need to set them all in parameter if they are alike, just with different copy indexes, only need to add the index in the resource content as my answer showed.

Comment: Why not you accept the answer when it helps you solve the problem? Why you ignore other's help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. You need to add the copy both in VM and the NIC, not the OS Disk.

A2. I suggest you just use the VM name suffix with the copy index, not like 01, 02 and etc. You can see the function [copyIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#copyindex). Then you can change the template for the Nic and VM that you provided like this:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex())]",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "nicLoop",
                "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[parameters('subnetID')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix, '-', copyIndex()]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
            "tags": "[parameters('tag')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "vmLoop",
                "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[variables('vmSettings').vmNamePrefix]",
                    "adminUsername": "[variables('vmSettings').adminUserName]",
                    "adminPassword": "[variables('vmSettings').adminPassword]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]",
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('dnsLabelPrefix'), '-os')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "createOption": "FromImage"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [ ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat(variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex())]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', variables('nicName'), '-', copyIndex())]"
            ]
        },
```